# HTTP POST Response Body is blank - 204 status

Tags: apex, rest-api, httprequest, httpresponse

I've changed the endpoint url and the json payload for security reasons but let's assume that I've tested the endpoint using advanced rest client and with the same json in my apex code and it works.

```
myJson: {
  "user" : "test@force.com",
  "pass" : "mypass",
  "url" : "https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/37.0",
  "type" : "New"
}
```

My callout looks like this

```
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
    Http http = new Http();

    String SessionId = Userinfo.getSessionId();
    String strURL = System.URL.getSalesforceBaseURL().toExternalForm();
    req.setEndpoint('https://myapp.herokuapp.com/webapi/myapi');
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeStringField('user', user);
        gen.writeStringField('pass', pass);
        gen.writeStringField('url', url);
        gen.writeStringField('Type',Type);
        gen.writeEndObject();              
        String myJson = gen.getAsString();
        req.setBody(myJson);

    try {
        req.setTimeout(120000);
        res = http.send(req);
    }
```

Here are my request and response

```
CALLOUT_REQUEST|System.HttpRequest[Endpoint=https://myapp.herokuapp.com/webapi/myapi, Method=POST]
CALLOUT_RESPONSE|System.HttpResponse[Status=No Content, StatusCode=204]
```

I'm having trouble identifying why this isn't working. The issue is, the response is empty. it's supposed to return a json.

Comment: So, you are saying that same POST request does not work from SF and works from other tool, like postman?

Comment: What exactly is the Problem? Status code 204 says everything worked well.

Comment: @AndreeWille It didn't return the json i was expecting. it's empty

Comment: What JSON do you expect. Status Code 204 means:

The server successfully processed the request and is not returning any content.

Comment: @AndreeWille i'm expecting a response from my api. and it's not coming through

Comment: can you check with the API provider if they are really giving you a content?

Comment: @SarathGarimella I get the json response when I test with a rest client. I posted below
 ` {
"name": "AccountTrigger"
},
  {
"name": "AccountController"
}
],`

Comment: @kurunve Yes. I get a response body back from testing with a rest client and status of 200 but get no response body in salesforce and status of 204

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that, even though the code is working, the http response body was empty. I set `req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');` on the request before sending it and that seemed to give me what I wanted. Cheers!